# Pandas ---> Need an index for each group element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My df:

| name | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2009-06-30 | some value 1 |
| A | 2010-06-30 | some value 2 |
| A | 2011-06-30 | some value 3 |
| B | 2019-12-31 | some value 4 |
| B | 2020-12-31 | some value 5 |
| B | 2021-12-31 | some value 6 |

I want

| name | date | value | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2009-06-30 | some value 1 | 2 |
| A | 2010-06-30 | some value 2 | 1 |
| A | 2011-06-30 | some value 3 | 0 |
| B | 2019-12-31 | some value 4 | 2 |
| B | 2020-12-31 | some value 5 | 1 |
| B | 2021-12-31 | some value 6 | 0 |

The final view will look like this (maybe pivot)

| name | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | some value 3 | some value 2 | some value 1 |
| B | some value 6 | some value 5 | some value 4 |

This is a serious problem for me. Please help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a descending [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['position'] = df.groupby('name').cumcount(ascending=False)
```

Then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df.pivot('name', 'position', 'value')
```